# how limit max zoom in dynamically updated HighStocks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I have a HighStocks app in Vue (it's not relevant that it's a Vue app, all Highcharts properties etc are relevant here). It first gets the data of a one point, and then it gets stock data every 5 seconds. The super simple version of it is available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-forked-w7ho3?file=/src/components/Chart.vue
So at the beginning it looks like that:
[image: at the beginning]

The thing is that after X seconds it looks super overloaded, like that:

[image: after a while]

So I wonder if I can limit the navigator in such a way that it will be zoomed at max to let's say 10 observations. But I cant' figure out how to do it in Highcharts/Highstocks.

Comment: Hi @Philipp Chapkovski, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r0agx6fk/. Do you want to achieve something like that?